# PhoneGap + jQueryMobile: Android back button closes app in nested list

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I'm creating an app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

Using jQuery Mobile I have created a nested list.

After clicking into the nested list I want to go back. I expect that clicking the back button on my Android device ([Nokia N1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N1)) that it will go back one level.

But instead android closes the app instead of going back up one level.

I am using PhoneGap 1.2.0, jQuery Mobile v1.0rc2, jQuery 1.6.4, and Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread).

I also upgraded to jQuery Mobile 1.0, and there is no change.

Comment: I started noticing this issue once I changed from Phonegap 1.1.0 to Phonegap 1.2.0, so I bet that's the culprit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got this same problem. I found out how to handle the back button in the Java code.

This goes back one step if possible or else exits the app.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    if(appView.canGoBack()){
       appView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It is also possible to do it on the JavaScript side:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
    //Logic//
}, false);
```

Comment: This worked at least for what I wanted it to do. Now the back button successfully makes a nested list go up one level.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the great answer.  It looks like Flatlineato may have answered your follow-up question below with his answer  ($.mobile.activePage gives you the current page).

Comment: Also, just for clarification:  The code Rob provided goes inside of the java class sitting in your src folder that extends the "DroidGap" class.  You should already have a method called "onCreate" in there.  :)

Comment: Why do we have to override this? Why isn't it phoneGaps default behavior? 99% of the scenario's we use the back button to go back (until we can't) don't we?

Comment: @VDP Android back-button switches activities. You're phonegap App is just one. So the default behavior would (rightly) be to shut your App down. And because there is no previous Activity you'll return to your home screen. I do agree this behavior isn't really 'native', but i guess PG wants to mess as little as possible with normal Android behavior. (Which, in the end, most developers are looking for.)

Comment: @Rob, You're right in most cases. But in this case, we're basically using Phonegap to build applications, in the broad sense. And applications have multiple activities. Since this is unique to Android's architecture, maybe Phonegap should include this little patch. I don't think its going to interfere with Android's behaviour, but rather gives us an avenue to emulate multiple activities - which is what we are basically wanting to do when creating a multi screened app.

Comment: also you will have import "KeyEvent" to handle the event... 
"import android.view.KeyEvent;"

Answer (score 12):

You can listen for back button events:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

And if the current page is the homepage (`$.mobile.activePage` in jQuery Mobile) exit from application with:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: Most people seem to answer this question by only mentioning how to catch the back button, so you get +1 for explaining what to do after it's caught.  If we had to manage the app's navigation history manually, then this may have been accepted as the right answer.  However, Rob's solution gets the app working like native Android again without the need for micromanagement.  Still, I've found the info in this answer useful, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also try:

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'main') {
         <!-- navigator.app.exitApp(); -->
         device.exitApp();
    }
    else {
         history.back(1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who came here because the app closes after having been in focused text-field and pressing the back button:

In Android 4.0.3 (ICS) you do not have to override the back button with the PhoneGap API to stop closing/crashing the app after having focused an input text-field and then pressing the back button. Normally this closes the app, because WebKit is creating a tap-highlight with an additional outline that can not be changed with CSS.

When you focus the input the soft-keyboard comes up. When you press the first time the backButton your softkeyboard disappears. When you click again to go back in navigation-history, the app is closing instead of jumping to the page visited before. This is because the highlighting jumps out of the navigation-structure. It seems like it is not in the DOM. I don't really understand that behaviour. Here is the solution:

Just add

```
input {
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only
}
```

This interrupts webkit doing a tap-highlight and you still stay in the app and can go back in History with your (not overridden) backButton.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because of the issue with the back button inside a text field (`input` or `textarea`) in a Cordova/PhoneGap app that doesn't trigger the normal behavior (in my case, it doesn't trigger my JavaScript handler).

Unfortunately, the above solution using CSS doesn't work on Android 2.3.

And the chosen solution, which overrides the event in Java, isn't enough for me because I need to trigger a JavaScript handler, not go back in the webview. Also, this solution is reimplementing the default Cordova behaviour, which is not best practice, as it loses other built-in features.

So, what I did (and it worked) was override the KeyUp event, as above, but instead of reimplementing it, I just called the handler on the appVIew (which is Cordova's implementation).

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return appView.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of using things like PhoneGap. They build applications the way that Android doesn't work.

The back button pops the latest activity of the activity stack. As you have a whole application that looks like multiple activities, it's in fact a single activity with overlays. What you will have to do, and keep in mind this, this isn't really the proper way of doing things.

You will have to override the functionality of the back button pragmatically to get it to go back in the jQuery stacks, and then once the flat Android application is the only thing that's left, go back from that too. I don't know if PhoneGap allows you to have that much control over the Android system, but by default, the Android OS won't act normally with your jQuery list.

I hope this provides some insight.